# Is it possible to auto upload to a drive folder, from a Wifi Sd Card ?

Tags: tethering, wifi-sd

I would like to create a tethering-like system at home.

I've a Pentax K-30 and I'm guessing if does exists a Wifi Sd Card that after a shoot, auto upload image to my Pc Hard Disk.

If yes, which wifi sd card model can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about something like a USB SD card reader?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options that you have, you might need to double check how they handle RAW, but each of these are SD cards which either function as their own WIFI network, or to my knowledge can join your WIFI network where you then run software on your PC/Mac/Mobile device which checks the card at a set interval and downloads the images accordingly.

I used to use an older version of EyeFi, but only with JPEG;

[EyeFi](http://www.eyefi.com/)
[FlashAir](http://www.toshiba-memory.com/cms/en/products/wireless-sd-cards/FlashAir/index.html)